# On Passage, Objections to the Contrary Notwithstanding

Tags: meaning-in-context, phrase-meaning, double-negation

What does the following mean? There seem to be a lot of double negatives in here, so I'd like to understand this better.

> On passage, objections of the president to the contrary notwithstanding

This assumes we're talking about political parties voting on some issue:

|  | AYE | NAY | PRES | NV |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| DEMOCRAT | 211 | 20 |  | 2 |
| REPUBLICAN | 109 | 66 |  | 20 |
| INDEPENDENT | 1 | 1 |  |  |
| TOTALS | 321 | 87 |  | 22 |

Comment: Your sentence is not complete, and can entail guessing answers. Try giving a better context.

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3GmDCD-J3dg   <-- turn to 1:43

Comment: It means "regardless of any objections that the president may raise (where he states something contrary to what is being said here)".

Comment: *Despite* (notwithstanding) the President's objections *that oppose* (to the contrary) the bill ... Yes, if you object to a thing, your objections are likely to be contrary to the thing.

Comment: Note that this is a vote to override a presidential veto.

Comment: This is standard language in the House of Representatives for a vote to pass a bill in spite of the president's objections.  The phrase is searchable and will reveal many other examples.

Answer (score 2):

This is legal language

On this [site](https://archives-democrats-rules.house.gov/archives/lph-pres.htm) I found this sentence which made me understand the expression better:

> `The question is, Will the House on reconsideration agree to pass the bill, the objections of the President to the contrary notwithstanding?`

which means that the bill may be passed ***despite*** the objections of the President ***not*** to pass it (to do the contrary).

So I would understand your expression in this way:

> On Passage ***(of some law or bill)***, ***(in spite of)*** Objections to the Contrary (Notwithstanding)

Bottomline, this law was passed in spite of all objection not to pass it.

Here is an [article](https://www.mondaq.com/unitedstates/contracts-and-commercial-law/272744/the-vices-and-virtues-of-notwithstanding) about the ambiguity of ***notwithstanding*** used in such constructions.

This [question](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/90327/myths-to-the-contrary-notwithstanding) might also enlighten you more (it explains another similar structure: "myths to the contrary notwithstanding").

Answer (score 2):

As Xanne has pointed out in the comments, this a set phrase regularly used in the documents of the U.S. Congress. Its intended meaning is:

> objections of the president[, which present arguments] to the
> contrary[,] notwithstanding.

What makes the phrase *objections to the contrary* confusing is that *objection **to** X*, normally means that the objection consists of some arguments against X. Consequently, *objection to the contrary of X*, taken at face value, would mean something consisting of arguments against a position that is contrary to X, which would amount to supporting X (the two negations cancelling out). This is clearly not what was intended here (if it had been, then the presence of *notwithstanding* would be puzzling).